# Determine the solutions to $e^z - ie^{\pi} = 0$ which absolute value is smaller than $2\pi$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given the equation
> $$e^z-ie^{\pi}=0 $$
> solve the equation for which $|z|<2\pi$.

**My attempt**

Manipulating the equation
$$e^z=ie^{\pi} $$
Let's take the natural log
$$\ln(e^z)=\ln(i)\cdot \ln(e^{\pi}) $$
$$z = \frac{i\pi}{2}+\pi $$
So I guess this is the only solution, but there is something bothering me. Why would they explicit state that they want us to find the solution, for which $\vert z \vert<2\pi$. I feel I have solved in a "wrong" way, because for this exercise I am not supposed to know what $\ln(i)$ is, but I just looked it up.

Is there different way to solve this, without using $\ln(i)$?

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write $|z|<2\pi$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right. Just edited.

Comment: The logarithm is multi-valued in the complex plane. I recommend looking back at the definition of the complex logarithm (it has two parts: the real part and the imaginary part...pay particular attention to the imaginary part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ie^\pi=e^{\pi i/2}e^\pi=e^{\pi+\pi i/2}$. So\begin{align}e^z=ie^\pi&\iff e^z=e^{\pi+\pi i/2}\\&\iff z=\pi+\frac{\pi i}2+2n\pi i\\&\iff z=\pi\left(1+\left(\frac12+2n\right)i\right)\end{align}for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! This is just what I wanted, thank you José.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$e^\pi i = e^\pi e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative

$$e^z-ie^{\pi}=0 \iff e^z=ie^{\pi}\iff e^x\cdot e^{iy}=e^{\pi}\cdot i$$

which requires

- $x=\pi$
- $y=\frac \pi 2+2k\pi$